# Inner join with 4 tables creating duplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT Analysed.resultId,bugOwner,Analysed.bugId as BugDet,bugType,testCaseName 
FROM Bug 
INNER JOIN Analysed 
ON Analysed.bugId=Bug.bugId 
INNER JOIN Results 
ON Analysed.runId=Results.runId 
WHERE Analysed.runId=64
```

The above works fine.

Now I have another table Results (resultId,runId,analysed,testname)

I also want to include testname in my other query so I added,

```
SELECT Analysed.resultId,bugOwner,Analysed.bugId AS BugDet,bugType,testCaseName 
FROM Bug 
INNER JOIN Analysed 
ON Analysed.bugId=Bug.bugId 
INNER JOIN Results 
ON Analysed.runId=Results.runId
WHERE Analysed.runId=64
```

But this query duplicates the records.I guess its taking some cross product or something. Does anyone know how to solve it ?

Comment: What if you try this:`select Analysed.resultId,Bug.bugOwner,Analysed.bugId as BugDet,Bug.bugType,Bug.testCaseName from Bug 
INNER JOIN 
Analysed on Analysed.bugId=Bug.bugId 
INNER JOIN Results on Analysed.runId=Results.runId
where Analysed.runId=64`

Comment: Title says it is four table and query only contains three table! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is that you have multiple rows in Results with same runId. If there's no way to limit them to just to the first one (e.g. always having runId 0 for the first record) you can fetch the first one that has a testCaseName with outer apply:

```
SELECT 
    A.resultId,
    B.bugOwner,
    A.bugId AS BugDet,
    B.bugType,
    R.testCaseName 
FROM 
    Bug B
    INNER JOIN Analysed A ON A.bugId=B.bugId 
    outer apply (
        select top 1 
            testCaseName
        from 
            Results R  
        where 
            A.runId=R.runId and
            R.testCaseName is not NULL) R
WHERE 
    A.runId=64
```